# In VB.NET, wait for a Timer Or a KeyPress

Tags: vb.net, loops, timer, keypress, semaphore

I have a console application which is intended to just keep running until it is killed. Essentially:

```
<setupCode> 

Do 
    <doProcessing>
    Thread.Sleep(<interval>)
Loop
```

Essentially this will keep running until the user kills it, obviously.

What I'd like to do is replace the `Thread.Sleep` call with a wait-condition waiting on either one of two separate events... something like

```
WaitFor(<intervalPasses> Or <KeyPress>)
```

so that the app will basically just sleep in the background until the next interval passes, but so that the user can "wake it up" with a keypress. I also want to be able to get the information about the keypress so that e.g. if they pressed Enter I can just start the next iteration without waiting for the timer and if they pressed Escape i would exit the loop altogether, and if they press anything else I would continue waiting for either the timer or one of those two keys.

Either `(waiting for a timer)` OR `(waiting for a keypress)` would be easy.
Waiting for either `(a timer OR a keypress)` I am not sure how to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Windows Forms and WPF work.  I'd strongly recommend you use one of them to implement this task.  Use a Timer, implement its Tick event.  And implement the form's KeyDown event.  Something like that, your question is too generic to be more specific.

Comment: I was hoping to keep it as a small, light-weight console app as it doesn't really have any user-interaction and just does background processing, if possible.

Comment: Meh, I guess I will go that route... it will give me other flexibility and options, so it'll be a good trade-off I guess. Thanks for the idea.